# How to write XSD Or conduction

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.0, xsd-1.1

I have a requirement to write or conduction in XSD. 
For an example memberName can be companyName or firstName or middleName or lastName. Any one Name should exist in xml document/Like any one Name is mandatory in XML.

```
<xs:element name="memberName" nillable="false">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="middleName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

complete XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://hidden"
    xmlns:tns="http://hidden" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.2.0">
    <xs:element name="accountNumber" nillable="false">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]" />
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="memberName" nillable="false">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="middleName" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>    
    <xs:element name="effectiveDate" nillable="false">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How to write restriction or OR conduction in XSD.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show a complete sample of your current XML Schema, together with an XML document you want to be valid against the schema and another which should be invalid. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @ Mathias Muller, We are developing new web service, Consumer will call my service with those fields. I will validate those values in my DB and create task in my app and send success or failure message to consumer.

Comment: "XSD Or conduction" does not make sense.  I suggest that you provide examples of XML that should be and should not be valid to help us understand what you're trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you mean is `xs:choice`, but I'm not sure yet.

```
<xs:element name="memberName" nillable="false">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="middleName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This would require that the `memberName` element contains exactly *one* of `companyName`, `firstName`, `middleName` or `lastName`.

But I'm sure most people have both a first name and a last name, so how about

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="4">
```

which would allow several of the child elements, but also several of the same kind.